# Where are Postman collections saved?

Tags: postman, postman-collection

Where does the [standalone Postman client](https://www.getpostman.com/) for Windows save collections when working offline?

To clarify, I want to find where Postman saves collection files to by default when online syncing is disabled. I am *not* trying to [export my collection as a JSON file](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/postman/collections/sharing_collections#sharing-as-a-file).

I've looked in `%LocalAppData%`, My Documents, and Program Files, but I don't see where Postman saves its collection data.

Comment: They make nice tool, and crap save system like this.

Comment: And will hold your data hostage if you don't keep up with online payments even if you don't need the service. They suck, use Insomnia instead.

Comment: lesson learned - don't ever upgrade postman without backing up your collections manually

Answer (score 154, accepted):

It looks like Postman uses [LevelDB](http://leveldb.org/). On Windows, I found my Postman DB located at:

```
%HOMEPATH%\AppData\Roaming\Postman\IndexedDB\
```

*ps: `%HOMEPATH%` is path for `C:\Users\xxxx\`*

*also worth mentioning: `%APPDATA%` is a shortcut for `C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Roaming\`*

[According to Piere F](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47399809/where-are-postman-collections-saved#comment95117639_49476443), macOS users can find it under:

```
~/Library/Application Support/Postman/IndexedDB
```

*ps: Note `~` is path for `/Users/userAccount/`*

[According to David](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47399809/where-are-postman-collections-saved#comment96886978_49476443), Ubuntu users can find it under:

```
~/.config/Postman/IndexedDB
```

Comment: I was able to locate leveldb with name as  `000005.ldb`.  how we can import to new postman in different  system, i'm using windows 10.

Comment: I pretty much copied over  whole postman folder to my new system and it worked
https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/2721

Comment: I get a warning, "cannot start postman" during the app splash screen. It never seems to advance from that point. It's too bad that something as basic as export to file doesn't exist.

Comment: For macOS users: I found my Postman DB under `~/Library/Application Support/Postman`

Comment: On Windows, you can use the shortcut `%AppData%\Postman\IndexedDB`

Comment: @Steven M . Vascellaro yepp, there’s a sub folder IndexedDB on macOS as well

Comment: It's `~/.config/Postman/IndexedDB` on my Ubuntu 18.04 machine.

Comment: I created a symlink from `~/Library/Application Support/Postman/IndexedDB` in my Mac to another folder I have under Git source control. This way I can access my collections in a centralized spot from anywhere in the world, and will have them persisted/memorialized forever.

Comment: This saved my life. I lost a bulk of my local collections when I moved to Workspaces. Thank you.

Comment: indexedDB is also in %AppData%\roaming\Postman\partitions\

Comment: You can locate all postman backup data inside `%HOMEPATH%\AppData\Roaming\Postman\` folder, all postman data should be saved in json format, something like `backup-{date}.json`

Answer (score 38):

Postman is using Chromium offline storage capabilities because at the end it's a SPA running inside Chromium ([Electron](https://electronjs.org/) technology).

From Postman's top menubar:

- Select **View → Show Dev Tools**
- Select the **Application** tab
- In the sidebar, open **Storage → IndexedDB → postman - file:// → collection_requests**

Comment: Do you know what folder this data is saved to?

Comment: I don't know (yet) but since Postman is using Chromium, I would look for a place similar to Google Chrome... see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9384128/how-to-delete-indexeddb-in-chrome

Comment: This helped me in getting a hint to restore lost collections too. See here: https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/2022#issuecomment-453128568

@StevenM.Vascellaro the folder would be "IndexedDB" as noted in my Github comment

Answer (score 8):

This support documentation helped me recover my collections after the postman application stopped working.

https://support.postman.com/hc/en-us/articles/360035071313-How-to-recover-my-data-

> If you weren't logged in to the app and using it offline or in the
> Scratch Pad mode then your data won't get synced to our servers and
> stays local to your instance. In this case, try following the steps
> below:
>
> Look for the backup files under the following folder:
> %appdata%\Postman\​for Windows ~/Library/Application
> Support/Postman​for macOS ~/.config/Postman​ for Linux
>
> Backup file names will be similar to
> backup-2020-02-26T23-13-43.082Z.json (date or time will be different
> for you).

Comment: Highly under-rated answer. This worked like a charm and saved me a lot of heartache. Never am I ever going to try and update my old postman version ( v6.x) ... Thank you !! Note: The backup was a 2 months old but it was still good enough. didnt lose much

Comment: link broken now :/  At least the quote is here thought!

Comment: For me backups were at AppData\Roaming\Postman.

Answer (score 7):

On Mac: The json files were automatically backed up (/Users//Library/Application Support/Postman/backup-YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSSZ.json) but it is not documented anywhere.
You just have to reimport them

Comment: This worked for me. But is imported both my local collection and the Team collections.

Comment: This is also present in Windows.

Answer (score 6):

In windows, postman v9.6.2 I was able to restore collections by pasting the IndexedDB folder in the following path:

```
\AppData\Roaming\Postman\Partitions\<GUID>\
```

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, if you just want to look at the collection, you can export it into json format from the collection menu.

Answer (score 3):

We work offline. So for [Postman Scratchpad](https://learning.postman.com/docs/getting-started/using-scratch-pad/) (official offline usage):

- On Windows: `%HOMEPATH%\AppData\Roaming\Postman\Partitions\`
- On Mac: `~/Library/Application Support/Postman/Partitions/`

Simply backup or share the entire directory when you want to synch.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a snapped Postman on Linux, let me save you some time.
Copy all the content from your source snapped Postman UNDER (as the target GUID can be different)

`/home/username/snap/postman/<id>/.config/Postman/Partitions/<standalone GUID>`

to your target snapped Postman UNDER

`/home/username/snap/postman/<a different id>/.config/Postman/Partitions/<a different standalone GUID>`

Make sure you respect the target postman id and partition GUID.

Comment: Wow! What a time saver! This saved my day! Thanks!  \(^__^)/

Answer (score 1):

For the version Postman from Google Chrome extension, you need copy all files from path:

"**%LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Storage\ext\fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop\def\IndexedDB\chrome-extension_...**"

The files inside path above contains all history and collections from Postman

Comment: As of 2020-09 with current Postman v7.32, this answer is no longer applicable.

Comment: STILL works in 2022

Answer (score 1):

Linux **Chrome** or **Chromium** Postman extension storage path Location

> `/home/{USER}/.config/chromium/Default/Storage/ext/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop/`

Thanks.

Comment: Mine is under /home/user/.config/google-chrome/Default/Storage/ext/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Win10:
You have to back up your old Postman
C:\Users%user%\AppData\Roaming\Postman\IndexedDB
Then copy it to the same location of the new Postman installation.

This will recover all your collections.

Answer (score 0):

In **Debian-like** systems, using Postman v7, I found a backup of all the collections and environments saved as JSON in `~/.config/Postman` with the prefix `backup-`.

eg:

```
~/.config/Postman/backup-timestamp.json
```

Also, found a recent support article in Postman documentation:
[How to recover my data](https://support.postman.com/hc/en-us/articles/360035071313-How-to-recover-my-data-)

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10, I copy these folder to another and worked.

C:\Users<username>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\IndexedDB\chrome-extension_coohjcphdfgbiolnekdpbcijmhambjff_0.indexeddb.leveldb

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I got files in under `\AppData\Roaming\Postman` as backup.json