# Where does Postman store current value of environment variables?

Tags: environment-variables, postman

I've been looking around my machine to see where the postman environment variables are stored. I've looked under `AppData\Local\Postman`, and `C:\Users\username\Postman` folders, and haven't found a config file that has a last modified date matching my change of environment variables.

I know I can export the environment variables, but I want to search over the current variables. And the exports don't include the current values, unless they replace the initial value, which I want to keep.

There are still ways to get around this. But I want to write a simple command to fetch some current environment variables via cmd, ex using grep.

So is there a way to check for the current environment variables? Where are they stored?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think this will be a successful attempt. Postman seems to use a database, e.g. leveldb, according to information I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47399809/where-are-postman-collections-saved). That will be stored as a binary file on your disk.

You can, however, have a look into the DB by going to **View => Developer => Show DevTools** and then going to **Storage => IndexedDB => variable_sessions => workspace**. I can find a current value for an environment variable like this:

[image]

But I don't see a way to search in this other than by keys which are uuids and not variable names or values.

All in all, exporting your environments into a text file might be the easiest option.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out where the data is stored locally. I see them, but as you mentioned it's easier to export the env variables, as otherwise it's a matter of looking at the data from the postman or the DB UI